# Output a JS variable in a div tag

Tags: javascript, html, tags, output

I know this question has been asked and answered a few times. but I don't quite understand them or know how to apply them to my code. I have a function with two parameters

```
updateTitle = "";
updateDescription = "";

function info(title, description){
    updateTitle = title;
    updateDescription = description;
}
```

My goal is to output this to my screen using div tags but I don't know how to do this.

What I have so far is:

```
<div id="updateTitle">Title: <title id="updateTitle"</title></div>

<div id="updateDescription"> Description: <description id="updateDescription"</description></div>
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What doesn't work? Where are you outputting the variables?

Comment: I'm trying to have title and description display on the screen but my tags don't do this

Answer (score 0):

ID's in HTML are unique. you have used same ID's. so I have modified it.

then I added a onclick to a div and dispalyed new title and descriptions.

```js
updateTitle = "";
updateDescription = "";

function info(title, description){
    updateTitle = title;
    updateDescription = description;
    document.getElementById('updateTitle').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('updateDescription').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('updateTitle1').innerHTML = updateTitle;
    document.getElementById('updateDescription1').innerHTML = updateDescription;
}
```

```html
<div id="updateTitle" style="display: none">Title: <div id="updateTitle1"></div></div>

<div id="updateDescription" style="display: none"> Description: <div id="updateDescription1"></div></div>

<div id="show" onclick="info('newTitle','newDesc')">show</div>
```

Comment: When i do this, the output is
[objectHTMLDivElement]
[objectHTMLDivElement]
show

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally added the comment before finishing, it should be fixed now

Comment: ok, my above snippet works right? if yes , just copy and try it. it will work fine

Comment: @katiedidkatie We can't help you with code you've posted. Make sure it is a [mcve].

Comment: @Don'tDownVote no, it doesn't work for me. I copied it and what I commented above is what shows up on the screen instead of the actual title and description

Comment: what are you passing in the `info` function? can you update that in ypur question?